# Series of meromorphic functions meromorphic?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb C$ be open with $0\in U$. For each $m \in \mathbb N$ we have a holomorphic function $f_m:U \setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb C$ with simple pole at $s=0$. We know that
$$F(s) := \sum_{m=1}^\infty f_m(s)$$
converges locally normally for $s \in U$ with $\Re(s)>0$ to a holomorphic function. Further, we know that
$$a_{-1}:= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \operatorname{res}_{s=0}(f_m(s))$$ converges. Does this imply that $F$ has a meromorphic continuation in a neighborhood of $s=0$ with simple pole at $s=0$ with residue $a_{-1}$? Further, if this is the case, is Laurent series at $s=0$ of $F$ simply the sum of the Laurent series of the $f_m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In fact there are various ways to show there exist *polynomials* $p_n$ with $$\sum p_n(s)=e^{1/s}\quad(\Re s>0).$$

Comment: Yeah, a few minutes after posting my question I came up with counter examples my self. For example modular forms are definied on the upper half plane and have no continuation but are expressible as Fourier series. Can you specify the polynomials for your example?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain I don't know that could "specify" the polynomials, but their existence follows for example from Runge's Theorem...